# Passing JS value into Php function without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to be able to pass my JS value into my php function whitout reloading page,indeed I use LeafLet for my map , and my function show popup informations on passing an Id on params

```
   var idcustom= custom[key];

               <?php $infopopup= $objects->ShowBindPopup($_SESSION['Users'],here i want to pass my "idcustom" var from js); ?>
```

I know that there is server/client difference , but i want to know an alterntive solution
Thanks for you'r help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: <?php $infopopup= $objects->ShowBindPopup($_SESSION['Users'],."<script>document.write(idcustom)</script>".); ?>

Comment: short answer: use Ajax

Comment: ++Robin: If you want to execute php without reloading the page. You can do this with ajax requests.
For instance if you would use a javascript library like jQuery, you can get the data with https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/. (examples can be found on the page)

Comment: I can't use ajax for this ,beaucause i got many ID to showup at the same time . Indeed I used leaflet, and i want to create specifcal popup for each markers